# What are the registry Device "LocationInformation" key sections for USB Devices?

Tags: c#, windows, usb, registry

I am currently iterating through a list of USB Cameras connected to my computer that I retrieved with the following code:

```
DsDevice[] cams = DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);
```

I then determine the HardwareID and InstanceID values from the DevicePath for each device, and I look up the following registry key for all devices:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB{HardwareID}{InstanceID}\

I then read the `LocationInformation` subkey value. Here are some examples of what I'm receiving based on which USB port the device is plugged in to:

```
0000.001a.0000.001.003.000.000.000.000
0000.001a.0000.001.004.000.000.000.000
0000.001d.0000.001.008.000.000.000.000
0000.001d.0000.001.007.000.000.000.000
0000.001d.0000.001.005.000.000.000.000
0000.001d.0000.001.006.000.000.000.000
```

1. It appears that the second block (index 1 of the returned `Split('.')` array) is a distinction between the internal USB hub that the USB port is connected to. Is this correct?
2. I have deduced that the fifth block (index 4) is the USB port number, but on a separate computer I'm using (an Intel Compute Stick), the port number differentiation actually occurs in the fourth block (index 3). Is there a way to know which block I need to check based on the computer? (Third-party libraries are acceptable though I'd much rather use built-in functionality of .NET or straight Windows APIs that I can hook into, if possible.)
3. Is there any documentation on what each section of the `LocationInformation` is? I have Googled for information, but I've come up short of what I'm looking for. Perhaps I just don't know the best search terms to find this information. In any case, I'd bet that this documentation could be extremely useful to other StackOverflow users as well.

Thanks!

Comment: for this need not read registry direct, but use *CM_* api. if you want *LocationInformation* call [`CM_Get_DevNode_Property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh780220(v=vs.85).aspx) with [`DEVPKEY_Device_LocationInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542547(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: That's helpful information but I'm more interested in the information that the registry value contains at this point. The code has already been written and is working reliably, but I would like to know what the specific blocks in the `LocationInformation` key value are referring to.

Comment: `LocationInformation` is string (`REG_SZ`) value. and it is used as is. tipical for usb strings like this `Port_#****.Hub_#****`

Comment: The period is a delimiter in the string value. #3 in my question asks what each of these sections refers to.